# Can't find "Additional Drivers" in dash after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: apt, software-center, software-sources, additional-drivers

I've upgraded 14.04 to 16.04. Now I can't find "Software & Updates" nor "additional drivers" in dash.

Also note that I have both "Ubuntu Software" and "Ubuntu Software Centre". In Software Centre > Edit menu > Software Sources is greyed out (not clickable).

Comment: 1) Please share the output of `cat /etc/lsb-release`. 2) Does `software-properties-gtk` open the Software & Updates window?

Comment: Btw, for the `software-properties-gtk`, launch it from console and share back any errors. Also, try a simple update & upgrade: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: Thank you it wasn't installed so just a `sudo apt install software-properties-gtk` did the thing. I didn't know the package name. You might want to post it as an answer. @SamuelSantana

Comment: Ok. I just did! I'm glad it worked out for you ;D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a console try the following command: `software-properties-gtk`, if it complains about the package missing, install it: `sudo apt install software-properties-gtk`.